Trying to create a script for Google Sheets to print/save one sheet as PDF for my end users
I have very little idea what I am doing.  I can find make this work in VBA in Excel, but trying to make this work in Google Sheets has been a challenge.  My end users need to be able to Print/Save as PDF.  I can make the script do that, but I only want to select one Sheet, and have a range.  My script is saving the entire worksheet as a PDF and with no formatting.
My code is saving a PDF of my Google Sheet in the local folder (makes it easy to find and the end users can do whatever with it from there).  However, it is saving the entire workbook and with no formatting. I've picked and pulled from various other threads, and examples online, but I cannot get the range to work. I would also love to be able to format.
function saveSheetAsPDF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Option Grants');
  
  if (!sheet) {
    Logger.log('Sheet "Option Grants" not found.');
    return;
  }

  // Create a temporary sheet
  var tempSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet();
  
  // Copy values, formats, and other attributes to the temporary sheet
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  range.copyTo(tempSheet.getRange(1, 1));
  
  // Save the temporary sheet as PDF
  var pdf = spreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(sheet.getName() + '.pdf');
  
  // Move the PDF to the desired location (e.g., root folder)
  var folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder(); // Change this to the desired folder
  folder.createFile(pdf);
  
  // Delete the temporary sheet
  spreadsheet.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
  
  Logger.log('PDF file saved locally: ' + pdf.getName());
}

I found this code which looks like it can format, but I don't know where to add it:
var PRINT_OPTIONS = {
  'size': 0,              // paper size. 0=letter, 1=tabloid, 2=Legal, 3=statement, 4=executive, 5=folio, 6=A3, 7=A4, 8=A5, 9=B4, 10=B
  'fzr': false,           // repeat row headers
  'portrait': true,       // false=landscape
  'scale': 3,             //1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
  'top_margin':0.25,      //All four margins must be set!
  'bottom_margin':0.25,   //All four margins must be set!
  'left_margin':0.2,      //All four margins must be set!
  'right_margin':0.2,     //All four margins must be set!
  'gridlines': true,      // show gridlines
  'printnotes':false,     //true/false'
  'printtitle': false,
  'sheetnames': false,
  'pagenum': 'UNDEFINED', // CENTER = show page numbers / UNDEFINED = do not show
  'attachment': false
}


I was able to find a solution.  It's not pretty but it works for my purposes.  Now I just need to figure out how to format the PDF.
function saveSheetAsPDF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Option Grants');
  const sheetName = "tempSheet"; // Please set the sheet name you want to export as PDF format.

  if (!sheet) {
    Logger.log('Sheet "Option Grants" not found.');
    return;
  }

  // Specify the range you want to save as PDF
  //var range = sheet.getRange('A1:O63'); // Adjust the range as needed

  // Create a temporary sheet
  var tempSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet("tempSheet");

  // Copy the specified range to the temporary sheet
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Option Grants\'!A1:P63').copyTo(tempSheet.getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Option Grants\'!A1:P63').copyTo(tempSheet.getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NO_BORDERS, false);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setHiddenGridlines(true);

  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  Logger.log(sheets.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== sheetName) {
      sheets[i].hideSheet();
    }
  }

  // Save the temporary sheet as PDF
  var pdf = spreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(sheet.getName() + '.pdf');

  // Move the PDF to the desired location (e.g., root folder)
  var folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder(); // Change this to the desired folder
  folder.createFile(pdf);

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== sheetName) {
      sheets[i].showSheet();
    }
  }

  // Delete the temporary sheet
  spreadsheet.deleteSheet(tempSheet);

  // Show a popup when the process is finished
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('PDF file has been created and saved in your Google Drive.');

  Logger.log('PDF file saved locally: ' + pdf.getName());
}

